# Grub: show menu with arbitrary key combination

Tags: grub, menu

I want to hide the grub menu at boot, and show it when a particular key combination is pressed. For example I want the grub menu to appear only when *a+b+c* keys are pressed.
(I am using Debian 8)

Now I am able to hide the grub menu and show it with the *`ESC`* key, working with the *`/etc/default/grub`* file, but I can't find a way to set this up to work as a key combination.

Do you know a way to do this?